# Cannot reset the resource statement or I go in an infinite loop

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite

I saw that I was getting code error 5 when I was trying to close the SQLite database.
So I struggled to reset all the resource used.
I believe that this is the method where I don't properly reset all the resources:

```
- (NSArray*) allObjects
{
    NSMutableArray* objects=[NSMutableArray new];
    // resource is an ivar of type sqlite3_stmt* , it has been initialized with   
    // sqlite3_prepare, a query where I select some rows of a table
    if(!resource)
    {
        return nil;
    }
    while(sqlite3_step(resource)== SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary* object=[NSMutableDictionary new];
        int count= sqlite3_column_count(resource);
        for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
        {
            // I need to know the type and the name of all columns to build
            // a dictionary object.Later I'll optimize it doing this only at 
            // the first loop iteration.
            const char* key=sqlite3_column_name(resource, i);
            int type= sqlite3_column_type(resource, i);
            const unsigned char* text;
            double value;
            switch (type)
            {
                case SQLITE_TEXT:
                    text=sqlite3_column_text(resource, i);
                    [object setObject: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%s",text] forKey: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%s",key]];
                    break;
                case SQLITE_INTEGER:
                    value= sqlite3_column_int(resource, i);
                    [object setObject: @(value) forKey: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%s",key]];
                    break;
                case SQLITE_FLOAT:
                    value= sqlite3_column_double(resource, i);
                    [object setObject: @(value) forKey: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%s",key]];
                    break;
                case SQLITE_NULL:
                    [object setObject: [NSNull null] forKey: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%s",key]];
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        // sqlite3_reset(resource);  Point 1
        [objects addObject: object];
    }
    // sqlite3_reset(resource);  Point 2
    return objects;
}
```

So if I put sqlite3_reset(resource) at point 2 when I close the database I get error 5, if I put it at point 1 I go in an infinite loop.
I'm almost sure the problem is in this function,I am also doing other things with the database, so the error may be in other parts of the code, but that's a lot of code.So if the problem isn't here write it in the comment and I'll post other "suspicious" part of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the "reset" at point #2. And then you should call `sqlite3_finalize` on the prepared statement when you don't need it anymore at all. You should also set the ivar to `nil` after doing this.

`sqlite3_reset` says you are ready to use the statement again. `sqlite3_finalize` says that you are completely done with the statement and its resources should be cleaned up.

An error 5 is `SQLITE_BUSY`. IF the "finalize" doesn't fix the problem, do some searching on causes of `SQLITE_BUSY`.

Comment: I use the same resource to do another query, shall I finalize it anyway?

Comment: You finalize it when it is not going to be used again, such as just before closing the database.

Comment: This is what I was doing before: make a query with sqlite3_prepare, use sqlite3_step, reset the resource and repeat this operation N times, then close the database and I was getting error code 5.But if I finalize it instead of resetting I don't get error 5, am I doing it right?

Comment: You prepare it once and you finalize it once. In between you call step and reset as many times as you need.